# Java Input method not terminating

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to work out this problem:

**Input**

The input stream contains a set of integer numbers Ai (0 ≤ Ai ≤ 1018). The numbers are separated by any number of spaces and line breaks. A size of the input stream does not exceed 256 KB.

**Output**

For each number Ai from the last one till the first one you should output its square root. Each square root should be printed in a separate line with at least four digits after decimal point.

---

**Sample:**

input:

```
1427  0   

876652098643267843 

5276538
```

output:

```
2297.0716

936297014.1164

0.0000

37.7757
```

---

And here's my code:

```
public class ReverseRoot 
{//start class
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {//start main
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Long> array = new ArrayList<Long>();
        array.add(in.nextLong());

        while(in.hasNextLong())
        {
            array.add(in.nextLong());
        }
        in.close();

        for (int i = array.size(); i > 0; i--)
            System.out.printf("%.4f%n", Math.sqrt((double)array.get(i)));
    }//end main
}//end class
```

Anybody know what the deal is?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with this to be certain this is the issue, but from the JavaDoc: "The next() and hasNext() methods and their primitive-type companion methods (such as nextInt() and hasNextInt()) first skip any input that matches the delimiter pattern, and then attempt to return the next token. Both hasNext and next methods may block waiting for further input. Whether a hasNext method blocks has no connection to whether or not its associated next method will block. "

Comment: Your while loop is running infinite. You have to break it somewhere

Comment: @FallAndLearn It runs until you enter a non-long character.

Comment: Does your input need to be on separate lines like that? If so, I don't think its possible without something to indicate termination.

Comment: @AdamRosini I mean, it's the 2nd "easiest" exercise on Timus Online Judge, so there's gotta be some way. I'm just not sure what that might be...

Comment: Yeah, looking at the problem you need a blank line at the end of the input :). You will need to do two loops, one nested within the other.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop doesn't work because you try to access non existing elements in your list.

Change the loop to this:

```
for (int i = array.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            System.out.printf("%.4f%n", Math.sqrt((double)array.get(i)));
    }
```

Why do you have `array.add(in.nextLong());` outside the loop? You can delete this.

To exit your input just type any non-long character into your console.

Comment: @FallAndLearn I tested the input code on my system and it works like expected.

Comment: @Blobonat I thought it was needed outside the loop to get it started, I guess?? Suppose not. Anyway, array lengths always seem to get me, so it makes sense for that to be the issue. Thanks!

Comment: It totally works! Unfortunately, the confines of the exercise say it should only need that input, no more. :-/

Answer (score 0):

As I observer, we should have 2 loops. The first loop is for 'multiple lines' and the second loop is for 'multiple long value' of a single line.

Here is an example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner lineTokenizer;

        // this is to handle all 'lines'
        while (console.hasNextLine()) {
            String lineContent = console.nextLine();

            if (lineContent == null || lineContent.isEmpty()) {
                // this is to exit the program if there is no input anymore
                break;
            }
            lineTokenizer = new Scanner(lineContent);

            // this is to handle a 'line'
            while (lineTokenizer.hasNext()) {
                if (lineTokenizer.hasNext()) {
                    long number = lineTokenizer.nextLong(); // consume the valid token

                    System.out.printf("%.4f%n", Math.sqrt((double) number));
                }
            }
            lineTokenizer.close(); // discard this line
        }

        console.close(); // discard lines.
    }
```